# preimages under group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\varphi : G \rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism with kernel $K$ and let $a,b \in \varphi(G)$. Let $X = \varphi^{-1}(a)$ and $Y = \varphi^{-1}(b)$. Fix $u \in X$. Let $Z=XY$. Prove that for every $w \in Z$ that there exists $v \in Y$ such that $uv=w$. This is Dummit and Foote exercise 3.1.2.

My attempt:

Suppose we assume that $v = u^{-1}w$

I try to show that $v \in Y$

$\varphi(v) = \varphi(u^{-1})\varphi(w) = a^{-1}\varphi(w)$

If I could somehow show $\varphi(w) = ab$, then $\varphi(v) = b$ so that $v \in Y$ but I think I am going in circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are also supposing that $w\in Z$ correct? That is, $w\in XY$ so that $w=mn$ where $m\in X$ and $n\in Y$ and so $\phi(w)=\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)=ab$.

Comment: Looking at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/754333/106586 I think I see my confusion. I knew the coset uKvK=uvK definition but not the other (equivalent) definition.

Comment: Looking at Dummit and Foote, I can't see where this equivalence is mentioned

Comment: Ok, the problem in question is on page 85 of D&F but the definition used for the notation Z=XY in the answers given so far are in D&F on page 93.  But then looking more closely, the defintion of the product of two fibers on pg 74 helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since $w\in Z$, you know that $w=xy$, for some $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

By definition, $\varphi(x)=a$ and $\varphi(y)=b$.

Also $\varphi(u)=a$, which implies $u^{-1}x\in\ker\varphi$.

Then
$$
w=xy=u(u^{-1}xy)
$$
Can you finish?